# Using CountVectorizer to creat a sparse matrix from list of files fails

Tags: python, list, sparse-matrix, countvectorizer

I hope I can get some help her. I'am trying to write a Python program which counts the words in every file with the CountVectorizer and after that creates a sparse matrix. I am creating a list with the directory to every file which should be analysed. The files have one word per line, that's why token_pattern is '+', so it splits the data at every newline. This works fine, but I get an exit code 1 when trying to transform it with fit_transform()[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3idH.png) and I just don't know what to do anymore.

```
import os
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
a = "C:/Datensatz/feature_vectors"
dirs = os.listdir(a)
filename_paths = []
for file in dirs:
    filename_paths.append(a + "/" + file)
print(filename_paths)
vec = CountVectorizer(input="filename", token_pattern="+", lowercase=False)
print("vec fertig")
sparse_matrix = vec.fit_transform(filename_paths)
print("sparse fertig")
```

Answer (score 0):

The token_pattern has to be ".+"